# How can I "form alter" fields in a nested Paragraph, depending on where the field is used

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have these entity types:

- A node type: `nodepage`
- A Paragraph type: `pg_a`
- A Paragraph type: `pg_b`
- A Paragraph type: `pg_child`

I have a content model which is:

```
nodepage
  ->field_a
    Referenced bundles: pg_a
      ->field_child
        Referenced bundles: pg_child
  ->field_b
    Referenced bundles: pg_b
      ->field_child
        Referenced bundles: pg_child
```

You can see that `pg_a` and `pg_b` both have a field called `field_child` which allows a reference to `pg_child`. This has great semantic meaning to the site architecture.

Now something I would like to do is form alter pg_child, but *only* when it is referenced from `pg_a` and not from `pg_b`.

In `hook_field_widget_form_alter`, where I *think* I should be doing my alters, I can do the following:

```
$field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();

// Get the current field widget being built, eg `field_child_thing`.
$name = $field_definition->getName();

// Get the bundle, ie. `pg_child`
$targetBundle = $field_definition->getTargetBundle();

// Get the bundle that $targetBundle is attached to in this instance...
$instance = ???
```

I thought I could look further into the $context variable, but so far this has alluded me. The best candidate so far is `#parents` in the form, but when I only find a reference to `field_child` which is ambiguous.

I now suspect I can inject more $context from somewhere, maybe in the parent build.

Answer (score 5):

In this scenario, we have `field_caption` being used in various places inside a `cta` paragraph. The business has asked to limit `field_caption` to 25 charaters, but only when it is being used in a node on an entity reference field called `field_foo_cta`.

First we add a #process callback to the widget based on whatever rule, by implementing `hook_field_widget_form_alter`:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$context) {
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();

  if ($field_definition instanceof FieldConfig) {
    $config = $field_definition->id();
    list ($entity_type, $bundle, $field_name) = explode('.', $config);

    if ($entity_type == 'paragraph' && $field_name == 'field_caption') {
      $element['#process'][] = ['\Drupal\mymodule\BusinessRules', 'alterFieldCaption'];
    }

  }
}
```

Then we create a new class in `src` directory of the module.

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule;

class BusinessRules {

  public static function alterFieldCaption(array &$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, array &$complete_form) {

    // Use whatever logic to target instances of `field_caption`.
    if (reset($element['#parents']) == 'field_foo_cta') {
      $element['value']['#maxlength'] = 25;
    }
    return $element;

  }

}
```

Thanks @larowlan for help on this.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I could look further into the $context variable, but so far
>   this has alluded me. The best candidate so far is #parents in the
>   form, but when I only find a reference to field_child which is
>   ambiguous.

Is the entity object available in $context? If not it may be inside $form_state somewhere.

Once you got the Paragraph entity you can get its parent using `Paragraph::getParentEntity()` and from there the type of the parent.

Comment: When the form is new, there is no existing object.